# Responsive website debugging on iOS browsers

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari

[My website](http://scott.rtcgraphics.com) is responsive, and looks perfect in mobile Chrome on my Android device, and performs really well in all browser-based emulators.

However, when I open the website on Safari on an iPhone 4S, and separately on an iPhone 6, the website has both styling issues and failed `javascript`.

Is there any way that I can debug the site on mobile iOS browsers?

Comment: Do you have a Mac?  http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787  Or even http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will look into these tools!